# Quartz job not running

Tags: spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling, quartz-core

I'm using the following beans for scheduling the quartz jobs:

```
package com.sap.brms.repositoryservice.cp.cf.app.config;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SimpleTrigger;
import org.quartz.Trigger;
import org.quartz.spi.JobFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean;

@Configuration
public class SchedulerConfig {

    @Bean
    public JobFactory jobFactory(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
        jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        return jobFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public Scheduler schedulerFactoryBean(@Qualifier("applicationDataSource") DataSource dataSource, JobFactory jobFactory,
                                          @Qualifier("sampleJobTrigger") Trigger sampleJobTrigger) throws Exception {
        SchedulerFactoryBean factory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        // this allows to update triggers in DB when updating settings in config file:
        factory.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setJobFactory(jobFactory);

        factory.setQuartzProperties(quartzProperties());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        Scheduler scheduler = factory.getScheduler();
        scheduler.setJobFactory(jobFactory);
        scheduler.scheduleJob((JobDetail) sampleJobTrigger.getJobDataMap().get("jobDetail"), sampleJobTrigger);

        scheduler.start();
        return scheduler;
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties quartzProperties() throws IOException {
        PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
        propertiesFactoryBean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("/quartz.properties"));
        propertiesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return propertiesFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobDetailFactoryBean sampleJobDetail() {
        return createJobDetail(SampleJob.class);
    }

    @Bean(name = "sampleJobTrigger")
    public CronTriggerFactoryBean sampleJobTrigger(@Qualifier("sampleJobDetail") JobDetail jobDetail,
                                                     @Value("0 * * ? * *") String cronExpression) {
        return createCronTrigger(jobDetail, "0 * * ? * *");
    }

    private static JobDetailFactoryBean createJobDetail(Class jobClass) {
        JobDetailFactoryBean factoryBean = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setJobClass(jobClass);
        // job has to be durable to be stored in DB:
        factoryBean.setDurability(true);
        return factoryBean;
    }

    private static SimpleTriggerFactoryBean createTrigger(JobDetail jobDetail, long pollFrequencyMs) {
        SimpleTriggerFactoryBean factoryBean = new SimpleTriggerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setJobDetail(jobDetail);
        factoryBean.setStartDelay(0L);
        factoryBean.setRepeatInterval(pollFrequencyMs);
        factoryBean.setRepeatCount(SimpleTrigger.REPEAT_INDEFINITELY);
        // in case of misfire, ignore all missed triggers and continue :
        factoryBean.setMisfireInstruction(SimpleTrigger.MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_RESCHEDULE_NEXT_WITH_REMAINING_COUNT);
        return factoryBean;
    }

    // Use this method for creating cron triggers instead of simple triggers:
    private static CronTriggerFactoryBean createCronTrigger(JobDetail jobDetail, String cronExpression) {
        CronTriggerFactoryBean factoryBean = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setJobDetail(jobDetail);
        factoryBean.setCronExpression(cronExpression);
        factoryBean.setMisfireInstruction(SimpleTrigger.MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_NOW);
        return factoryBean;
    }

}
```

My quartz properties are as following:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=spring-boot-quartz-demo
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=5
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold=60000
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=RULE_QRTZ_
org.quartz.scheduler.classLoadHelper.class=org.quartz.simpl.ThreadContextClassLoadHelper
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval=20000
```

The class SampleJob is:

```
public class SampleJob implements Job {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SampleJob.class);

    public SampleJob() {}

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        logger.info("Metering Job called");
    }
}
```

I have a postgres database installed on my local system, and when I run the spring boot application, the application runs however the SampleJob is never triggered. The application is a spring boot application with the version being 1.2.5.

Comment: Either add @EnableScheduling in configuration class or add scheduleFactory bean. For the later case, you will need to register each job to the scheduler.